# VB .NET BC30002 VB.NET Type is not defined - circular dependency DLL workaround not always working

Tags: vb.net

I had this working in the past but something must have changed. This could be related to a circular dependency, but I resolved that by pointing to the built DLL. Visual Studio 2017.

Error I am getting:
BC30002 VB.NET Type is not defined

Things I tried:

1. Cleaning solution and re-building
2. Making sure .NET framework are identical
3. Rebooting computer

```
    Dim overlay As StudyCSharp.OverlayQuestion = New StudyCSharp.OverlayQuestion  'Object   'set it to object to avoid circular dependency
    'Dim overlay As Object = CreateObject("StudyCSharp.OverlayQuestion") 'Keep to avoid early binding with circular depenendency
```

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you read all the details in those images?  Neither can I.  Rethink your question and provide only the information that is relevant.

Comment: Which image are you having trouble clicking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We re-wrote the code without a circular dependency to solve. We did have some minor success by adding the DLLs to the build folder manually but it only worked on 1 computer. We were able to convert the code from C# to VB to combine it into the same project. Boy I wish Microsoft would try to automatically solve the circular dependencies themselves by building the files one function at a time.